# Assign Cell to Matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to assign the value in a cell vector to a same dimension vector in a matrix and I use the following code,

```
ma(j,index) = temp2(:,3);
```

But it gives me value: Conversion to double from cell is not possible.

my temp2(:,3) is 25*1 cell and my ma(j,index) is the jth row with index columns in the double matrix ma

Comment: So did my answer help?

Answer (score 2):

Since `ma` is a 2D cell array, assigning a single element to a cell array requires the use of curly braces:

```
ma{j,index} = temp2(:,3);
```

Comment: how easy was it for you to identify this problem? is it just a given that bracket type is curly?

Comment: Yup. With cell arrays, writing individual elements require curly braces. That's the syntax. You use round braces when slicing into a cell array, which you aren't doing here.

Comment: I am a different daniel, btw

Comment: Are you questioning my identity? I cant tell if that is a sarcastic sure, but the ambiguity did make me laugh.

Comment: @DanPowers oh sorry. I wasn't questioning. I said sure to acknowledge your comment.

Comment: no need to apologize, it just wanted to say it made me laugh.